# how to find total keyspace size using nodetool in cassandra?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, cassandra, nodetool

I want to sum "**Space used (total): 0**" for all tables listed by **nodetool tablestats metadata**. can anyone have idea how to do this? please help.

Desired code: Add **Space used (total)** value for all tables; like below:

```
 for Table: dbtimestamp 
         size += value(Space used (total)) 
         Table: dbtimestamp_compressed 
         size += value((Space used (total)) 
         Table: migration_status 
         size += value((Space used (total))



----------------------------------------------------------------------------

nodetool tablestats metadata
    Total number of tables: 584
    ----------------
    Keyspace : metadata
            Read Count: 296
            Read Latency: 0.23686486486486488 ms
            Write Count: 68611
            Write Latency: 0.02151582107825276 ms
            Pending Flushes: 0
                    Table: dbtimestamp
                    SSTable count: 0
                    Space used (live): 0
                    Space used (total): 0
                    Space used by snapshots (total): 0
                    Off heap memory used (total): 0

                    Table: dbtimestamp_compressed
                    SSTable count: 0
                    Space used (live): 0
                    Space used (total): 0
                    Space used by snapshots (total): 0
                    Off heap memory used (total): 0

                    Table: migration_status
                    SSTable count: 2
                    Space used (live): 13014
                    Space used (total): 13014
                    Space used by snapshots (total): 0
                    Off heap memory used (total): 80

                    Table: reporttimestamp_by_type
                    SSTable count: 2
                    Space used (live): 121332
                    Space used (total): 121332
                    Space used by snapshots (total): 0
                    Off heap memory used (total): 112
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following(since you haven't mentioned samples so couldn't test it).

```
awk '/Space used \(total\)/{sum+=$NF} END{print sum}'  Input_file
```

Comment: There is no file. I'm using **nodetool tablestats metadata** command output as input which i have given above in the question block.

Comment: @ParulChourasia, if there is no file then do like `your_command | my_above_awk comand` and let me know then how it goes?

Comment: Below given is my awk output, in which i need sum of 4th column.

**nodetool tablestats metadata -H | awk '/Space used \(total\):/{print $0}'
   Space used (total): 12.71 KiB
   Space used (total): 118.49 KiB
   Space used (total): 0 bytes
   Space used (total): 0 bytes    
   Space used (total): 20.89 KiB**

used below command:

**nodetool tablestats metadata -H | awk '/Space used \(total\):/{sum+=$4} End{print sum}'**
it not printing anything.

Comment: @ParulChourasia,please post `nodetool tablestats metadata -H` output once in code tags and let me know then?

Comment: i have given output of command at top , in the question block.

Comment: @ParulChourasia, yes I checked that and it worked for me then only I have posted my answer. What error are you getting?

Comment: I was using 'End' instead of 'END'. Now everything is correct and working as desired. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, I had misspelled 'END' command in the awk statement.corrected it like below:

```
nodetool tablestats metadata -H | awk '/Space used \(total\):/ {sum += $4} END {print sum}'
```

Comment: You need NOT to add this answer as I have given this answer :)

Comment: yeah ok... just tried to give corrected version of my syntax. And i voted earlier for your answer too.

Comment: No harm in adding your own question's answer  but  only when you don't have similar answers, you could EDIT my answer. Add a EDIT line and write it your edited code. And one more thing just for your knowledge up-vote and correct answer is 2 different things,cheers and happy learning.